# Content besides tooltip are visible

Tags: css, highcharts, overflow, transparency, visibility

Am displaying a chart using highchart and data table below it, When i hover over chart tooltip should display, If the tooltip overflow the chard continer div then the tooltip is transperent and text beside the tooltip are visible, Please check the image attached

Note: opacity is set at 1 and background white [image: h]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing further code, it's just guessing the problem.
Perhaps this article will help solve this problem.

[z-index article from mozilla dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Or maybe u have some positioning errors, take a look at this:

[positioning article from mozilla dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)

But in the first place, for me it looks like a `z-index` problem.

Comment: Thanks @J4R, I found solution,The problem is in position, I set position as static for  th and td then it workes.